# Azure Functions Schedule Timer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

It is possible that on Azure functions beta the timer has a bug or did I something wrong?

My cron timer in the application settings was this:

```
59 23 * * * *
```

and the last run was on 2018-02-21T17:23:59.0307645+00:00

How should I set the cron timer if I want to have every day at 23:59?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression you currently have (`59 23 * * * *`) means "every hour at 23 minutes and 59 seconds). What you need to use instead is `0 59 23 * * *`. Note that by default, this will be treated as UTC time.

Be aware that CRON expressions have lots of dialects, and I don't think the other answer will work. My answer is specifically for Azure Functions, which uses [ncrontab](https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab) (the flavor of it that supports the 'seconds' field).

Comment: I will try this tonight but i think this would fix my problem. i'll let you know

Answer (score 0):

**Everyday at 23:59:** 0 59 23 1/1 * ? *

[Source](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Comment: Strang because the documentation points on this side https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression and if I understand right the first thing are the minutes. Or I am wrong?

Comment: If I use your expression -> 59 23 * * * * on the site I linked, it states that the expression is invalid. I don't know much about it, theoretically, per say, althought I've worked with it quite a lot in the past, but I've always used CronMaker, to generate/check my expressions. If I find something relevant to your question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Note the _"CronMaker uses Quartz open source scheduler. **Generated expressions are based on Quartz cron format.**"_

Comment: @cpiock did you get that wikipedia article by following microsoft's tutorial on  creating Azure functions that are triggered by a timer? If so, take a closer look at the example. The expressions they use there, have seconds first. (0 */1 * * * * -> for every minute + 0 0 */1 * * * -> for every hour).

Comment: @stuartd yeah, after you pointed it out, I noticed OP didn't state anywhere they were using Quartz.

Comment: OP is using Azure Functions. Please see my answer for the correct cron expression to use.

Comment: found the wikipedia article by using this help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function

Comment: @cpiock Thats the doc I mentioned. If you check the examples, they use seconds first and not, minutes first, as stated in the wikipedia article.